# Export a List of All Mailboxes in a Distribution Group

Tags: powershell, exchange-server-2010

I'm trying to export a CSV list of all mailboxes in a distribution group:

```
Get-DistributionGroupMember -Identity "GroupA"
```

which will give me a list of everyone's name. However, I also need their PrimarySmtpAddress. The problem is when I run a script:

```
$Users = Get-DistributionGroupMember -Identity "GroupA"

foreach ($User in $Users) {
  Get-Mailbox -Identity $User | Select-Object DisplayName, PrimarySmtpAddress
}
```

I get the following error:

> Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'Identity'. Cannot convert the "@Name{Bob Smith}" value of the type "Deserialized.Selected.Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.Management.ReducedRecipient" to type "Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.tasks.MailboxIDParameter".

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. By changing adding `.name` to `$User` it passed the correct information to `Get-Mailbox`.

It passed the information correctly through and I was able to then do this

```
$List foreach ($User in $Users) {
  Get-Mailbox -Identity $User.name |
    Select-Object DisplayName, PrimarySmtpAddress
}

$List | Export-Csv C:\ExportedList.txt
```

I had to move the `Export-CSV` to outside the `foreach` loop. By adding all the `foreach` results to `$List` I was able to export the entire list. If the `Export-Csv` was inside the `foreach` loop, it only exports one result. The above way was the easier way for me to implement this.

Comment: You could also have done this: `$Users = Get-DistributionMember -Identity "GroupA" | Select-Object -Expand Name`

Comment: Oh okay. Thank you. I was sure there was a way to do this easier but I was sort of working backwards figuring out how to get this to work.

Comment: Oh I think you meant `Get-DistributionGroupMember` and not `Get-DistributionMember`

Comment: If that's what you meant. I just copy/pasted that part from your question. ;)

Comment: BTW, I was just pointing out an alternative. The way you used is perfectly fine.

Comment: Ahh thanks for pointing that out. I changed it in the original questions. I like knowing alternatives as well. Thanks again.